# How to know end of PDF File on Auto IT

Tags: autoit

I have an AutoIT script to open and scroll to end of PDF file by mouse action. By the number of times for scrolling is depended on the zoom percent and the number of pages. How do I determine the end of PDF file for configure the number of times for scrolling?
Below is the sample script. I fixed the number of times for scrolling is 15

```
Func OpenAllPDFFile($vardirectory)
    If @error = 1 Then
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Path is invalid.", 2)
    ElseIf @error = 4 Then
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "No report(s) found.", 2)
    ElseIf @error Then
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Fail to open report", 2)
    Else
        $FileArray = _FileListToArray($vardirectory, "*.pdf",1)
        $NewFileArray = SortPDFFile($FileArray)
        For $i = 0 To UBound($NewFileArray)-1
        ShellExecute($vardirectory & "\" & $NewFileArray[$i])
        ConsoleWrite("Opening pdf file: " & $NewFileArray[$i] & @CRLF)
        if WinWaitActive($NewFileArray[$i]) Then
            ConsoleWrite("Pdf file " & $NewFileArray[$i] & " is opened" & @CRLF)
            WinSetState($NewFileArray[$i], "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
            Sleep($varSleep)
            ControlClick($NewFileArray[$i], "", $varZoomPercent)
            ControlSend($NewFileArray[$i], "", $varZoomPercent, $vPercent)
            Send("{ENTER}")
            Sleep($varSleep)
            For $y = 0 To 15
                If WinExists("[CLASS:AcrobatSDIWindow]") Then
                    MouseWheel($MOUSE_WHEEL_DOWN, 12)
                    Sleep($varSleepRead)
                Else
                    ExitLoop
                EndIf
            Next
        Else
            ConsoleWrite("Could not find pdf file: " & @CRLF)
        EndIf
        WinClose("[CLASS:AcrobatSDIWindow]")
        Next
    EndIf
    WinClose($varDUTPlot,"")
EndFunc
```

Comment: you need to indent your code with 4 spaces in order to syntax coloring - do it next time please

Comment: What about sending GoToPage MaxNr instead of scrolling?

Comment: Why not just use `Send("{CtrlDown}{End}{CtrlUp}")`?

Answer (score 0):

If you really just need to go to the end of the PDF I would use Page Down like this:

```
Send("{PGDN down}") # hold key down
Sleep(10000) # hold it for 10 sec
Send("{PGDN up}") # stop holding it
```

You can increase or lower the time just by editing the sleep time(in ms).

I don't know how to scale it with the PDF size.

If you know the pagecount it would be easy. ;)

```
$c = PAGES_IN_PDF
$t = $c * 200 # plan enough time for slow PCs
Sleep($t)
```